# Problema error de Contexto con Angular2c

Tags: angular, typescript

Mi codigo es simple un boton que muestra una lista pero no entiendo el error que me arroja solo dice

```
ERROR Error: "StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NgIf -> TemplateRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NgIf -> TemplateRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for TemplateRef!"
```

cual es el error en el codigo ?

mi componente

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Pelicula} from '../modelo/pelicula';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-lista-peliculas',
  templateUrl: './lista-peliculas.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./lista-peliculas.component.css']
})
export class ListaPeliculasComponent {
  public pelicula:Pelicula;
  public mostrarDatos:boolean;

  constructor() {
    this.pelicula = new Pelicula(1, "El caballero de la Noche", "Christopher Nolan", 2008 );
    this.anuncio();
    this.mostrarDatos = false;
  }
  anuncio(){
    console.log(this.pelicula);
  }
  botonMostrar(){
    this.mostrarDatos = true;
  }
}
```

y mi html

```
<h2 class="titulo-lista">Listado de Peliculas</h2>
<button (click)="botonMostrar()">mostrar peliculas</button>
<ul ngIf="mostrarDatos === true">
  <li>Pelicula: {{pelicula.titulo}}</li>
  <li>Director: {{pelicula.director}}</li>
  <li>Anio: {{pelicula.anio}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TL;DR: es `*ngIf` con asterisco, no `ngIf`

El error está en que no estás usando la directiva del if de manera correcta. Te falta el asterisco (*): `*ngIf`

Tienes que repararlo así:

```
<ul *ngIf="mostrarDatos"> 
  <li>Pelicula: {{pelicula.titulo}}</li>
  <li>Director: {{pelicula.director}}</li>
  <li>Anio: {{pelicula.anio}}</li>
</ul>
```

En la [documentación te explican](https://angular.io/guide/structural-directives#asterisk) que el asterisco significa que estás usando una `directiva estructural`. La directivas estructurales forman y deforman el HTML que escribiste en directivas normales, pero simplificando su uso para mejor entendimiento del escritor del código y para el lector. Detras de todo esto Angular expande el `*ngIf` en las directivas correspondientes, que también podés usar directamente si querés tener todo el control, pero no son generalmente usadas.

Por ejemplo, tu código se puede volver a escribir como:

```
<ng-template [ngIf]="mostrarDatos">
   <ul> 
     <li>Pelicula: {{pelicula.titulo}}</li>
     <li>Director: {{pelicula.director}}</li>
     <li>Anio: {{pelicula.anio}}</li>
   </ul>
</ng-template>
```

Que es exactamente lo que Angular hará al compilar. Pero como verás no hay mucho beneficio para vos como desarrollador y menos para el que tenga que leer tu código.

Pocas veces me he visto obligado a usar las directivas directamente. Pero si entiendes el inglés sería bueno que leas la documentación que te enlacé arriba. Entender el uso de las directivas estructurales, el uso de `ng-template` y `ng-container` te permite hacer otras cosas interesantes como reusar plantillas, escribir HTML que sea más dinámico (busca el uso de ngSwitch), etc.

Por cierto, nótese que en hice un pequeño cambio en tu código de `<ul *ngIf="mostrarDatos === true">` a `<ul *ngIf="mostrarDatos">`. Podés jugar con un `*ngIf` casi como jugas con un `if (...)` normal de JavaScript.

Comment: @gerardo-bautista Si mi respuesta fue de ayuda puedes aceptarla. Así otras personas también pueden beneficiarse.

Comment: Me ha funciona perfecto Nery, agradezco tu respuesta. Saludos!

Answer (score 0):

Debes estar usando la etiqueta  `<template>...</template>` en uno de tus templates de tus componentes.

Cambia el  tag y usa `<ng-template>...</ng-template>.`